# Angular with Underscorejs, won't return where()

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

This controller takes a list of categories from a service (that takes it from a JSON file), and then it should take only one category from the list:

```
function CategoryCtrl($scope, Category, $stateParams, _) {
  $scope.categories = Category.query(function (categories) {
      $scope.category = _.where(categories, { id: $stateParams.category_id });
      console.log("sp.c_id: " + $stateParams.category_id);
      console.log("categories: " + categories);
      console.log("category: " + $scope.category);
  });
```

However, this does not work. Console output is:

```
sp.c_id: 1 
categories: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] 
category:
```

If I switch the underscore command with an array index though, like this:

```
$scope.category = categories[$stateParams.category_id];
```

I obtain a category ( but the wrong one, because id <> index).

Underscore is injected through a service,like this:

```
angular.module('underscore', []).
    factory('_', function() {
    return window._;
    });
```

Any idea of what could be going wrong?

EDIT: JSON file

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Close Reading","created_at":"2013-09-11T00:19:00.906Z","updated_at":"2013-09-21T13:21:05.123Z","subtitle":"Deliberate, careful reading will improve students’ grasp of every text."},{"id":2,"name":"Choosing Complex Texts","created_at":"2013-09-11T00:20:26.072Z","updated_at":"2013-09-21T13:21:07.698Z","subtitle":"What should your students be reading?"},{"id":3,"name":"Writing \u0026 Language","created_at":"2013-09-11T00:20:31.219Z","updated_at":"2013-09-21T13:21:08.008Z","subtitle":"What are the foundations of good written communication?"},{"id":4,"name":"Vocabulary","created_at":"2013-09-11T00:20:52.209Z","updated_at":"2013-09-21T13:21:08.824Z","subtitle":"Discover ways to expand students’ vocabulary."},{"id":5,"name":"Speaking \u0026 Listening","created_at":"2013-09-11T00:20:59.205Z","updated_at":"2013-09-21T13:21:09.744Z","subtitle":"Improve communication skills in your classroom."},{"id":6,"name":"Media Literacy \u0026 Technology","created_at":"2013-09-11T00:21:04.671Z","updated_at":"2013-09-21T13:21:10.042Z","subtitle":"Explore and apply the latest trends in digital media."},{"id":7,"name":"Differentiation","created_at":"2013-09-11T00:21:09.644Z","updated_at":"2013-09-21T13:21:10.363Z","subtitle":"Different students have different needs."},{"id":8,"name":"Reading Support","created_at":"2013-09-11T00:21:18.683Z","updated_at":"2013-09-21T13:21:10.820Z","subtitle":"Enrich your students’ reading experience."},{"id":9,"name":"Engagement \u0026 Motivation","created_at":"2013-09-11T00:21:35.022Z","updated_at":"2013-09-21T13:21:11.766Z","subtitle":"What makes students thirsty for learning?"},{"id":10,"name":"Performance Task Assessment","created_at":"2013-09-11T00:21:39.589Z","updated_at":"2013-09-21T13:21:12.107Z","subtitle":"Prepare students for the next generation of assessment."}]
```

Comment: Is it possible that there is no category with id 1?

Comment: The categories are numbered 1 to 10. However, why would this make a difference?

Comment: That's what where function does. It is looking for categories with id of 1.

Comment: Can you post the JSON file content please?

Comment: The function looks for categories where id: $stateParams.category_id, not id: 1, necessarily. The id is coming from a url that is generated in a different page, in which the categories are used to create the links using an Angular filter (which here I can't use for other reasons). Also, it seems to work with _.filter instead. I'll edit in the JSON.

Answer (score 3):

This probably happens because `$stateParams.category_id` is a string. You should be able to fix this by converting it to an integer:

```
$scope.category = _.where(categories, { id: parseInt($stateParams.category_id) });
```

Keep in mind `where()` method will return an array. If you want to get a single instance, use `findWhere()` method.

```
$scope.category = _.findWhere(categories, { id: parseInt($stateParams.category_id) });
```